# Python : SpaqrlWrapper, Timeout?

Tags: python, timeout, sparqlwrapper

I am new to python as well as new to the world of querying the semantic web. 
I am using SPARQLWrapper library to query dbpedia, I searched the library documentation but failed to find 'timeout' for a query fired to dbpedia from sparqlWrapper.

Anyone has any idea about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBPedia uses Virtuoso server for it's endpoint and `timeout` is a virtuoso-specific option. SparqlWrapper doesn't currently support it.

Next version will feature better modularity and proper vendor-specific extensions might be implemented after that, but I guess you don't have time to wait.

Currently, the only way to add such parameter is to manually hardcode it into your local version of library

Comment: True, I guess the only option now is to manually code the timeout. BTW thanks for writing back, I felt that wasn't able to locate the timeout in the library and was searching for it all the while. This marks end to my search ;)

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018, you can use `SPARQLWrapper.setTimeout()` to set the timeout for `SPARQLWrapper` requests.

Answer (score 1):

As Karoo mentioned you can use `SPARQLWrapper.setTimeout(timeout=(int))`.
If you want a timeout as a float, go to the `Wrapper.py` module and change `self.timeout = int(timeout)` to `self.timeout = float(timeout)` in the `def setTimeout(self, timeout):` function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is specifically an answer for your question, but I searched for it for ages and heres my solution for anyone else having trouble with Virtuoso specific timeouts on SPARQLWrapper:

Your can use this line of code to set a server-side timeout for your queries (not clientside like .setTimeout):

```
[your SPARQLWrapper entity].addExtraURITag("timeout","[your timeout in ms]")
```

In my case it looks like this:

```
s.addExtraURITag("timeout","10000")
```

This should give you 10 seconds of time before your query stops searching and returns results instead of just giving you a Timeout error.

Hope I could help anyone.

Comment: Thanks for this but even after setting the timeout to 0 i.e. to run completely, sometimes I get a partial response, any ideas why? [dbpedia-partial-result](https://www.dbpedia.org/resources/sparql/#:~:text=Partial%20Results%20for%20Timed%2DOut%20Queries%20(Anytime%20Queries)) [timeout 0 settings](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/anytimequeries/#:~:text=Setting%20the%20timeout%20to%200%20returns%20to%20the%20default%20state%20of%20having%20no%20limit%20on%20query%20run%20time%20and%20always%20returning%20complete%20results.)

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Sounds like there is a default timeout that is used!

Comment: good guess. It looks like this specific to DBpedia, they have a MaxQueryExecutionTime of 120sec, so even if we set it to 0 in code, they are maintaining a default settings.